# gwt panel flow panel

Tags: gwt, panel

i like to design entire html with GWT.

but when i press ctrl and +  then entire html must be zoomed from center not from upper left
corner.

then what type of panel should i use?

flow panel , stack panel i dont know.

Answer (score 1):

Any, but your root panel should have a fixed (or minimum) width and be centered.
Flowpanels are based on divs, so that's what you probably want.